# Did the Federation Ever Revisit the Central Barrier Planet?

Tags: star-trek, the-final-frontier

In Star Trek V: The Final Frontier,

> The Enterprise A discovers that the "danger" surrounding the Great Barrier in the center of the Milky Way galaxy is just an illusion or at least not as deadly as everyone had believed, and that a planet of interesting origin lies within, with a very powerful energy being living upon it.

Did the Federation ever re-visit this location? Or was it cordoned off as off-limits to all ships? Are there any in-universe explanations as to whether Starfleet has ever re-visited this location?

Comment: This is an example of ST:V many trivial problems.  If the script said it was a one off wormhole to some mystery planet no one would ever think of it again.  God living at the center of the galaxy is a problem because the people watching the movie know better than the people making it that there are 100 billion other galaxies.  I anticipate the only other callback to the alien trapped there was in a Q continuum novel which may have a beta canon answer for you

Comment: Well the creature ended up not being “god” though. Just an advanced (and clearly psychotic) energy being. My main question was whether or not SF ever revisited it or if ships were just told to stay away just like the Genesis planet.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if God popped up in Lower Decks at some point.

Comment: In The Autobiography of James T. Kirk is it speculated that movie never happened. “ Star Trek V: The Final Frontier, was presented as a movie they watched on the planet in which Bread and Circuses takes place. According to this book, Star Trek V apparently never happened, and was just a bizarre movie produced by a planet that had cultural contamination with very close lookalike actors, and a lot of Federation details done right.” - https://thesffblog.com/2018/01/the-autobiography-of-james-t-kirk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate resorting to Beta canon but here is the only answer.

> The One was still trapped within the barrier in 2374. The malevolent entity 0 had set the USS Enterprise-E on a course to free The One, but was stopped by the combined efforts of Q and the Calamarain long before reaching the barrier. (TNG novel: Q-Strike)
>
> <sub>Memory Beta page for [The One](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_One)</sub>

> The Great Barrier is an immense energy field surrounding the galactic core of the Milky Way Galaxy. It was created 500,000 years ago by the Q Continuum to imprison The One for its crimes. (TNG - The Q Continuum novel: Q-Strike)
>
> <sub>Memory Beta page for the [Great Barrier](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Barrier)</sub>

Comment: This doesn't relate to the planet inside the barrier, but rather the barrier itself.

Comment: @Valorum how do you not realize that getting to the barrier that surrounds the planet is a prerequisite to getting to the planet.  There is one example in a non canon novel of the Federation getting anywhere near that planet again, and it was stopped.   That's the answer.

Comment: The barrier is vast and surrounds a globe 7000ly across.

Comment: @Valorum - How is that relevant as a criticism? It's an explanation of why they can't get to the central barrier planet, the fact that it also means they can't get to a bunch of other planets doesn't invalidate that.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - It's relevant because the barrier isn't the planet. It's like asking if someone has been to Paris and saying "Well, they went to Europe"

Comment: But the barrier surrounds the planet. If someone asked me why I couldn't visit a relative in Paris, and I said that because of COVID there was a new EU-wide law banning all American travelers from crossing the border into any part of the EU, do you think this would somehow fail to explain why I couldn't go to Paris?

Comment: @Hypnosifl sometimes Valorum gets really basic things wrong despite his point count.

Answer (score 3):

Outside of post-Roddenberry books, they would never return because Roddenberry himself was very much against this plot line.  In one of his biographies (I believe it was this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Star-Trek-Creator-Authorized-Roddenberry/dp/0451454189](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0451454189)) there is included this letter he wrote to the studio with a long list of all the stupid things in that movie, including the fact that at high warp it was still impossibly far to get to the center of the galaxy (the galaxy is divided into four quadrants, so think of the center of very roughly half as far away as poor Voyager got stuck). I also remember the complaint that "Vulcan's don't ride unicorns."

One might wonder why, if the Star Trek creator disapproved, it went in anyway.  Roddenberry never was sole owner of Star Trek rights, in TV the studio usually has a lot of ownership.  With some of the movies, he just had no input or control.